# Need help finding an old 90s edutainment game with "Number Line" Train

Tags: apple-macintosh, identify-this-game

This is an old edutainment game that I used to play at school. We used Mac OS 9 there. This game taught you all about various subjects (possibly focusing on math?), all taking place in a zoo or similar.

The one game I can remember the most was one involving a train and the "Number Line". You would solve questions based on adding/subtracting large numbers to move along the Number Line to get to your destination.

Anything helps at this point! I'd love to play this game again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description sounds pretty much like:

["Mighty Math Zoo Zillions"](https://edmark.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Math_Zoo_Zillions):

> Mighty Math Zoo Zillions is a computer game by Edmark in the Mighty Math series. It teaches math and has animals and activities. […]
>
> Activities
> […]
>
> - Number Line Express

[And it was designed to run on:](https://macintoshgarden.org/games/mighty-math-zoo-zillions)

> [image]
>
> Compatibility: Architecture: 68k, PPC; Mac OS 7–9, 256 colours, […]